# Prove polynomial is irreducible in $Z_p[x]$.

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Give $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n$ and prime $p$ that $p \nmid a_n$ and $GCD(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=1$. Which one in two clause below is correct?

(1):"If $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ then $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.

(2):"If $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ then $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$".

I have prove that (1) is wrong and i think (2) is correct but i can't prove it.

Comment: If we denote by $\overline{f}$ the reduction of a polynomial $f$ modulo $p$, then you should be able to verify that for all polynomials in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ we have the implication
$$f(x)=g(x)h(x)\implies \overline{f}(x)=\overline{g}(x)\overline{h}(x).$$ The claim follows from this together with Gauss lemma and the assumption $p\nmid a_n$. Do you see why?

Comment: This has been handled (not necessaily very verbosely) many times on our site. See [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68771/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1035780/11619) linking to [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial). It gives a useful way of proving the irreducibility of polynomials in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$. See [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2632041/11619) for a typical deduction.